# Swift : telling callback to run on global queue

Tags: swift, concurrency, io

I'm running a background upload task but I found it's blocking the main thread. After looking I suspect this happens because 3rd party library (Firebase in this case) must be scheduling its async callback on the main thread.

Is there a way to explicitly make the callback run on the global thread?

Here's how I start the task from the main thread:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
  PhotoUploadOperation().start()
}
```

Here's an oversimplified version of the upload task:

```
class PhotoUploadOperation {
  func uploadCameraRoll() {
    for element in photos {
      self.uploadPhoto(element.image, uid) { url in
        // Some work

        if let url = url {
          let photo = Photo(uid: uid, url: url, creationDate: element.date)
          self.sendPhoto(photo: photo) { success in
            // Some work
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that the upload is blocking the main thread?

Comment: Could you post your Swift version, xCode version. And how you do know firebase block your thread?

Comment: @cora 2 things: (1) app scrolling in one of the views is too glitchy while upload task is running (2) I printed isMainThread in all code blocks within the upload task and in multiple instances the main queue was indeed running these blocks.

Comment: @pc13 You would not be able to do any scrolling if the main thread was blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this solution?

Firebase or other 3party framework use "method swizling" to accomplish some network log or other things. But your scenario is a little bit different.

```
extension DispatchQueue {
    
        static func background(delay: Double = 0.0, background: (()->Void)? = nil, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                background?()
                if let completion = completion {
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay, execute: {
                        completion()
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
DispatchQueue.background(delay: 3.0, background: {
    // do something in background
}, completion: {
    // when background job finishes, wait 3 seconds and do something in main thread
})

DispatchQueue.background(background: {
    // do something in background
}, completion:{
    // when background job finished, do something in main thread
})

DispatchQueue.background(delay: 3.0, completion:{
    // do something in main thread after 3 seconds
})
```

And you dont forget allow background processing from Signing and Capabilities
[image]